# Google Billing Client Error: client is already in the process of connecting to billing service

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-console

I'm trying to integrate Google Play subscriptions into my app using the official Google [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate). I have already created my subscription in the Google Play Console.

Below is the relevant code in my activity.

```
class ProfileSettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityProfileSettingsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityProfileSettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val purchasesUpdatedListener =
            PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->
                // To be implemented in a later section.
            }

        binding.btnUpgradeAccount.setOnClickListener {

            val billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
                .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .build()
            var isBillingClientConnected = false
            var billingClientReconnectCount = 0
            var billingResultError = ""

            while (!isBillingClientConnected && billingClientReconnectCount < 10) {
                billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
                    override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                        billingResultError = billingResult.debugMessage
                        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                            isBillingClientConnected = true
                            billingClientReconnectCount = 0

                            if (billingClient.isFeatureSupported("subscriptions").responseCode != BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    this@ProfileSettingsActivity,
                                    "Subscriptions are not supported on this device.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                ).show()
                                return
                            }

                            val queryProductDetailsParams =
                                QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                                    .setProductList(
                                        ImmutableList.of(
                                            QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                                .setProductId("product_id_example")
                                                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                                                .build()
                                        )
                                    )
                                    .build()

                            billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(queryProductDetailsParams) { queryBillingResult,
                                                                                                productDetailsList ->
                                if (queryBillingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                                    productDetailsList.forEach {
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                            this@ProfileSettingsActivity,
                                            "${it.name} => ${it.description}",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                        ).show()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            isBillingClientConnected = false
                            billingClientReconnectCount++
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                        isBillingClientConnected = false
                        billingClientReconnectCount++
                    }
                })
            }

            if (!isBillingClientConnected && billingClientReconnectCount >= 10){
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Couldn't retrieve subscription information. $billingResultError",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Every time I run this code by building directly from android studio into my device, the toast in the last if condition executes and prints:
`Couldn't retrieve subscription information. Client is already in the process of connecting to billing service`

What I expected to happen was my subscription details to be printed.

So I have two questions:

1. Why is my client failing to connect?
2. How does my client know where to get the subscription details anyway? I didn't see any place in the tutorial where I could link up a live or dummy subscription config.

**EDIT 1**

Removed the retry mechanism with the while loop and added a progress bar for a visual representation of when tne billing client connects or fails to connect. Currently the progress bar just loads indefinetly.

```
 binding.btnUpgradeAccount.setOnClickListener {

            binding.prbUpgradeLoading.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            val billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
                .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .build()
            var isBillingClientConnected = false
            var billingClientReconnectCount = 0
            var billingResultError = ""
            var billingResultCode = ""

            billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
                override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                    billingResultError = billingResult.debugMessage
                    billingResultCode = billingResult.responseCode.toString()
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@ProfileSettingsActivity,
                        "Billing setup finished.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                        isBillingClientConnected = true
                        billingClientReconnectCount = 0

                        val queryProductDetailsParams =
                            QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                                .setProductList(
                                    ImmutableList.of(
                                        QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                            .setProductId("product_id_example")
                                            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                                            .build()
                                    )
                                )
                                .build()

                        if (!billingClient.isReady) {
                            binding.prbUpgradeLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@ProfileSettingsActivity,
                                "Google Play Billing Client is not ready.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                            return
                        }

                        if (billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS).responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                            binding.prbUpgradeLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@ProfileSettingsActivity,
                                "Google Play subscriptions are not supported on this device.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                            return
                        } else if (billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS).responseCode != BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                            binding.prbUpgradeLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@ProfileSettingsActivity,
                                "An error occurred when connecting to the Google Play service. Please try again later.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                            return
                        }

                        billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(queryProductDetailsParams) { queryBillingResult,
                                                                                            productDetailsList ->
                            if (queryBillingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                                binding.prbUpgradeLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                                productDetailsList.forEach {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        this@ProfileSettingsActivity,
                                        "${it.name} => ${it.description}",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                    ).show()
                                }
                            }else {
                                binding.prbUpgradeLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                                isBillingClientConnected = false
                                billingClientReconnectCount++
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        binding.prbUpgradeLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                        isBillingClientConnected = false
                        billingClientReconnectCount++
                    }
                }

                override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                    binding.prbUpgradeLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@ProfileSettingsActivity,
                        "Billing service disconnected.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                    isBillingClientConnected = false
                    billingClientReconnectCount++
                }
            })
        }
```

**EDIT 2**

I moved the connection initialization outside of my button's click listener and I can now establish a connection.

```
        val purchasesUpdatedListener =
            PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->
                // To be implemented in a later section.
            }

        val billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build()
        var isBillingClientConnected = false
        var billingClientReconnectCount = 0
        var billingResultError = ""
        var billingResultCode = ""

        billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
            override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                billingResultError = billingResult.debugMessage
                billingResultCode = billingResult.responseCode.toString()
                Log.e("ProfileSettingsActivity","Billing setup finished. ${billingResult.responseCode}")

                if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    isBillingClientConnected = true
                    billingClientReconnectCount = 0
                    Log.e("ProfileSettingsActivity","Client OK 1.")
                } else {
                    Log.e("ProfileSettingsActivity","Client not OK 1.")
                    isBillingClientConnected = false
                    billingClientReconnectCount++
                }
            }

            override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                Log.e("ProfileSettingsActivity","Billing service disconnected.")
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@ProfileSettingsActivity,
                    "Billing service disconnected.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
                isBillingClientConnected = false
                billingClientReconnectCount++
            }
        })

        binding.btnUpgradeAccount.setOnClickListener {
            Log.e("ProfileSettingsActivity","Button clicked.")
            val queryProductDetailsParams =
                QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                    .setProductList(
                        ImmutableList.of(
                            QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                .setProductId("product_id_example")
                                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                                .build()
                        )
                    )
                    .build()

            if (!billingClient.isReady) {
                Log.e("ProfileSettingsActivity","Client isn't ready.")
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@ProfileSettingsActivity,
                    "Google Play Billing Client is not ready.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            if (billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS).responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("ProfileSettingsActivity","Subs not supported.")
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@ProfileSettingsActivity,
                    "Google Play subscriptions are not supported on this device.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            } else if (billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS).responseCode != BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                Log.e("ProfileSettingsActivity","Client not OK 2.")
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@ProfileSettingsActivity,
                    "An error occurred when connecting to the Google Play service. Please try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(queryProductDetailsParams) { queryBillingResult,
                                                                                productDetailsList ->
                if (queryBillingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    Log.e("ProfileSettingsActivity","Client OK 2.")
                    productDetailsList.forEach {
                        Log.e("ProfileSettingsActivity", "${it.name} => ${it.description} => ${it.productType} => ${it.productId}" +
                                " => ${it.oneTimePurchaseOfferDetails} => ${it.title}")
                        it.subscriptionOfferDetails?.forEach { innerIt ->
                            Log.e("ProfileSettingsActivity", "${innerIt.offerId} => ${innerIt.offerTags} => ${innerIt.offerToken}" +
                                    " => ${innerIt.basePlanId} => ${innerIt.pricingPhases}")
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                    Log.e("ProfileSettingsActivity","Client not OK 3.")
                    binding.prbUpgradeLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                    isBillingClientConnected = false
                    billingClientReconnectCount++
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're probably getting a different error to start, but you keep trying without addressing it in your loop, so it gets overwritten with "already connecting" from the previous iteration of the loop. That's probably not the sort of thing you want in a tight loop like that.

Comment: @dominicoder I removed the while loop and noted that the code inside the ```onBillingSetupFinished``` or the ```onBillingServiceDisconnected``` never execute. It just goes straight to the last if condition. Might you know why this is the case?

Comment: `startConnection` is an asynchronous call. That will take time before either callback will return. In the meantime, the next line will continue to execute, which is your if block. Your error handling should happen within those callbacks. [Per the documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#connect_to_google_play), your retry logic should happen in the `onBillingServiceDisconnected` callback.

Comment: @dominicoder I removed the retry mechanism and decided to just focus first on establishing a connection (check the edit in my question). It seems like the connection is loading indefinitely. Have I implemented the callbacks incorrectly or could there be another cause?

Comment: You are creating the billing client and callback inside the click listener - so you might be losing them both to garbage collection since you're not holding a strong reference to either. You should probably initialize them both _once_ and then call the `startConnection` method in the click event.

Comment: @dominicoder I moved the ```startConnection``` method outside of the click listener (check edit 2) and I'm now able to connect and get my subscription details, thanks. BTW, do you know the answer to this question that I asked originally? "How does my client know where to get the subscription details anyway? I didn't see any place in the tutorial where I could link up a live or dummy subscription config."

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "subscription details". I've not used the billing library myself, but the docs show [how to query for products](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#show-products) and [how to test](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test).